# How do I have a different logback logger for specific exceptions?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I want to use a more verbose logging pattern for certain exceptions but not for everything as I don't want the performance hit where I can avoid it.

Is there a way to define a logger such that it will only apply to specific exceptions?

(I'm using xml config, so examples in that format would be preferred if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion words handling exceptions already [support for filtering exceptions](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#xThrowable) in PatternLayout. Filtering exceptions is done via [evaluators](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Evaluators). It seems to me that the support you need is already there.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the level of a logger like so:

```
 <logger name="package.name" level="INFO"/>
```

where package.name is the name of the specific package.

You can specify different appenders (basically logging configurations) like so:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>myApp.log</file>

  <encoder>
    <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

Here, the file one prints log information to a file, and the STDOUT appender prints logging information to the console, as can be seen by the FileAppender and ConsoleAppender classes.

Now, combining the examples I have given above leads to this:

```
 <logger name="package.name">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </logger>
```

This allows you to define different logging for specific packages. So, if you had all of the exceptions you wanted to add extra logging to in the same package, this should do the job.

Comment: This answer doesn't specifically cover the case I want, but I'm starting to think I may have to just add the extra logging at package level and accept the minor performance hit from doing so.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood. Is it specific classes you want? Or is it even more specific than that? You want the logging for exception x to be different in class y and z?

Comment: What I really want is whenever I receive a 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException' for that to go through an additional logger, regardless of what class it has originated in.

Comment: Ahh ok, so predefined exceptions?

As far as I'm aware, the only way this would be achievable would be if you created your own exception that you threw every time the SocketTimeoutException was thrown, and configure the logging for that exception. Sorry to not be of more help.